# phonegap camera not loading image into <img> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am trying to use the navigator.camera object to capture an image and push it into an img tag.  I am doing what the demo says in the phonegap docs like this:

```
if(navigator.camera) {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(function(imageData){
        var $image = document.getElementById('imageForTask');
        image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
        console.log(imageData);
       }, null, {sourceType:1, quality: 50});               
} else {
    alert("Camera not supported on this device.");
}
```

When I do this though, I get a broken link in the imageForTask .  This is what the source says: `data:image/jpeg;base64,content://media/external/images/media/325`.  Does anyone know why this wouldn't work?  I have been wrestling with this for awhile.  Thanks!

-Geoff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default destinationType has been changed from DATA_URL to FILE_URI. If you add an option:

```
destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
```

to the options you pass to get picture you will be able to set it as base64 encoded data.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.6.1/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#cameraOptions_options

Answer (score 0):

`content://media/external/images/media/325` is the path to an image, not its actual binary data. You'll need to use the filesystem API to get the contents of the file, base64 encode it, and use that.

Comment: Do you have an example on how to use that?  I would like to see how it's done for future reference.

Comment: I'd like to stick `content://media/external/images/media/325` right into an `<img src="" />` tag. Why can't we do that? A similar process works on chrome and ios simulator.