# Setting Image retrieved from Cordova Camera Plugin in IMG tag

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, cordova

I am trying to use the Apache Cordova Camera API for displaying the image retrieved from the camera. I am getting the camera call, and able to click the picture. I am getting the file url as

file:///mnt/.....something.jpg

Now, I am not able to set this image in an existing image tag, using jQuery.

The Code I have used is:

```
$("#img").attr("src", "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData);
```

where imageData is the return value of the camera success callback.

The Options for Cordova Image function, which I am using

destinationType = 0;
sourceType = 1;
encodingType = 0;

There is no image which comes up on the  tag.
What can be the issue here?

Comment: Could you add your html code to check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a quick example about how this should work:

```
function changePhoto(){
        var cameraSuccess = function(imageURI){
            //add dummy param to disable caching
            var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
            var newImagePath = imageURI + "?dummy=" + random;
            $("#img").attr("src",newImagePath);
        };
        var cameraError = function(msg){
            alert(msg);
        };

        navigator.camera.getPicture( cameraSuccess, cameraError, { 
            quality: 50, 
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
        });
    },
```

Comment: doesn't seem to be working for me. I am getting a path such as file:///... but I cant get it to show in the img tag

Comment: This actually solved it for me
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10419383/phonegap-camera-not-loading-image-into-img-tag?rq=1